# Generating Eclipse AXIS Web Service Get Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, exception, axis

I am developing Java AXIS Web Services using Eclipse. When I create a new Dynamic Web Project and sometimes when I right click on my class -> Web Serves -> Create Web Serves

[image]

It creates everything fine, but when I want to test I sometimes get the following exception:

> Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Message: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException `

[image]

Googling it said:

> I should check the cause (e.getCause() or e.getTargetException()) exception to find out the problem.

But cannot seem to catch this exception in my method, but taking the same code and running it in an Java application it works fine.

How can I resolve this exception?

I am using:

- Eclipse Juno Service Release 2
- Tomcat 7
- AXIS (I believe its 1 not 2)